# Convert Encoded XML Tags To Nodes

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have the following XML obtain via a SOAP call.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
    <GetValueListForFieldResponse xmlns="http://URLHere/webservices/">
        <GetValueListForFieldResult>
            &amp;lt;SelectDef&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Id&amp;gt;1736&amp;lt;/Id&amp;gt; &amp;lt;SelectName&amp;gt;Values List&amp;lt;/SelectName&amp;gt; &amp;lt;GlobalFlag&amp;gt;False&amp;lt;/GlobalFlag&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Sort&amp;gt;1&amp;lt;/Sort&amp;gt; &amp;lt;SelectDefValues&amp;gt; &amp;lt;SelectDefValue&amp;gt; &amp;lt;guid&amp;gt;aaf6f3a7-6a74-4187-b4e7-3a9355b16796&amp;lt;/guid&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Id&amp;gt;14692&amp;lt;/Id&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Name&amp;gt;Open&amp;lt;/Name&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Description&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Description&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Color&amp;gt;#000000&amp;lt;/Color&amp;gt; &amp;lt;DefaultFlag&amp;gt;False&amp;lt;/DefaultFlag&amp;gt; &amp;lt;SortOrder&amp;gt;1&amp;lt;/SortOrder&amp;gt; &amp;lt;select_id&amp;gt;1736&amp;lt;/select_id&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/SelectDefValue&amp;gt; &amp;lt;SelectDefValue&amp;gt; &amp;lt;guid&amp;gt;f5082b54-d799-4fdc-80c1-0e232b360057&amp;lt;/guid&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Id&amp;gt;14693&amp;lt;/Id&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Name&amp;gt;Closed&amp;lt;/Name&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Description&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Description&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Color&amp;gt;#000000&amp;lt;/Color&amp;gt; &amp;lt;DefaultFlag&amp;gt;False&amp;lt;/DefaultFlag&amp;gt; &amp;lt;SortOrder&amp;gt;0&amp;lt;/SortOrder&amp;gt; &amp;lt;select_id&amp;gt;1736&amp;lt;/select_id&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/SelectDefValue&amp;gt; &amp;lt;SelectDefValue&amp;gt; &amp;lt;guid&amp;gt;94e29e78-2ab3-463f-bbb6-ab7f36003c7f&amp;lt;/guid&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Id&amp;gt;14780&amp;lt;/Id&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Name&amp;gt;Past Due&amp;lt;/Name&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Description&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/Description&amp;gt; &amp;lt;Color&amp;gt;#000000&amp;lt;/Color&amp;gt; &amp;lt;DefaultFlag&amp;gt;False&amp;lt;/DefaultFlag&amp;gt; &amp;lt;SortOrder&amp;gt;2&amp;lt;/SortOrder&amp;gt; &amp;lt;select_id&amp;gt;1736&amp;lt;/select_id&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/SelectDefValue&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/SelectDefValues&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/SelectDef&amp;gt;
        </GetValueListForFieldResult>
    </GetValueListForFieldResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Is there a way to convert the data in the GetValueForFieldResult node to actual XML so I can parse the data?

Below is how I'm making the SOAP call and storing the XML.  I'm learning C# and if below is a complete mess my appologies.

```cs
HttpWebRequest reqVl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverURL + "/ws/Field.asmx");
reqVl.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://URL/webservices/GetValueListForField");
reqVl.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
reqVl.Accept = "text/xml";
reqVl.Method = "POST";

using (Stream stm = reqVl.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
    {
        stmw.Write(VLsoap);
    }
}

WebResponse responseVL = reqVl.GetResponse();
Stream responseStreamVL = responseVL.GetResponseStream();
XmlReader rdrVL = XmlReader.Create(responseStreamVL);

XmlDocument vls = new XmlDocument();
vls.Load(rdrVL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to achieve what you want - however, please read the text afterwards for an explanation of why this may not be the best way to get what you want.

Tested as working with your message and .Net 4.

Assuming vls contains your SOAP message as XML, we split the problem into two halves; parsing the soap message, and extracting and decoding the contents of the `GetValueListForFieldResult` node into a string that can be loaded into another `XmlDocument`

**Part I** - getting the contents of the `GetValueListForFieldResult` node

```
  XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(vls.NameTable);
  namespaceManager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
  namespaceManager.AddNamespace("default", "http://URLHere/webservices/");

  XmlNode payLoadNode =
    vls.SelectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/default:GetValueListForFieldResponse/default:GetValueListForFieldResult", namespaceManager);

  string encodedXml = payLoadNode.InnerText;
```

**Part II** - getting the encoded string into an Xml Document

It is at this point that we have the encoded string. We have a couple of choices for decoding this HTML; as I'm using .Net 4 I've gone for the simplest:

```
  string decodedXml = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(encodedXml);

  XmlDocument payloadDocument = new XmlDocument();
  payloadDocument.LoadXml(decodedXml);
```

If you are using .Net 3.5 then you'll have to consider adding a reference to System.Web and using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` instead to decode the string.

Parsing your message above gives me the result:

```
<SelectDef>
  <Id>1736</Id>
  <SelectName>Values List</SelectName>
  <GlobalFlag>False</GlobalFlag>
  <Sort>1</Sort>
  <SelectDefValues>
    <SelectDefValue>
      <guid>aaf6f3a7-6a74-4187-b4e7-3a9355b16796</guid>
      <Id>14692</Id>
      <Name>Open</Name>
      <Description></Description>
      <Color>#000000</Color>
      <DefaultFlag>False</DefaultFlag>
      <SortOrder>1</SortOrder>
      <select_id>1736</select_id>
    </SelectDefValue>
    <SelectDefValue>
      <guid>f5082b54-d799-4fdc-80c1-0e232b360057</guid>
      <Id>14693</Id>
      <Name>Closed</Name>
      <Description></Description>
      <Color>#000000</Color>
      <DefaultFlag>False</DefaultFlag>
      <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
      <select_id>1736</select_id>
    </SelectDefValue>
    <SelectDefValue>
      <guid>94e29e78-2ab3-463f-bbb6-ab7f36003c7f</guid>
      <Id>14780</Id>
      <Name>Past Due</Name>
      <Description></Description>
      <Color>#000000</Color>
      <DefaultFlag>False</DefaultFlag>
      <SortOrder>2</SortOrder>
      <select_id>1736</select_id>
    </SelectDefValue>
  </SelectDefValues>
</SelectDef>
```

**The Alternative**

The reason you may not wish to do it this way is because the response you are receiving has been wrapped using SOAP; you may therefore wish to try and consume the service you are connecting to as a web service and generate a proxy library; this will encapsulate all of the code you see above, as well as the code you have written, in a proxy that may allow you to retrieve the values you want in a more type safe and less fragile manner. Support for this is built into .Net.

Further, as the URL you are connecting to terminates in ASMX, it tells you that this is most likely a native .Net web service so wiring your client up to it should be simple.

The MSDN topic "[How to add a Reference to a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)" should help you in generating the proxy and avoiding all of the code above.

Comment: Thanks dash, your code worked like a charm.  I would have used a reference but I need to keep all the code inline; no code behind.